# Insert an object from a List (dropdownmenu) into mongodb

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin, drop-down-menu, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to master Mongodb and jetpack compose and I understand the basic principle of adding information into a mongoDb. However I have been trying to solve a problem for a while now but without success. This is my current problem:
I have a dropdownmenu of lets say 3 items (lets say colors: Blue, Green and Red)
How can I make it so that when the user uses the dropdownmenu and selects an item, lets say the color Green. It will save this color into the mongo database. However if the user later changes to the color Blue. It will update the mongodatabse with this new color.

How can I achieve this?

My main Class called Person:

```
class Person : RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.invoke()
    var color: RealmList<Color> = realmListOf()
}

class Color: EmbeddedRealmObject {
    var type: String = ""
}
```

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
var name = mutableStateOf("")
var objectId = mutableStateOf("")

var colors = realmListOf<color>()

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        MongoDB.getData().collect {
            data.value = it
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
fun insertColors(color: RealmList<Color>) {
    this.color = color
}


fun insertPerson() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        if (color.isNotEmpty() {
            MongoDB.insertPerson(person = Person().apply          
                color = this@HomeViewModel.color
            })
        }
    }
}
```

DropDownMenu:

```
@Composable
fun Demo_ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
    list: RealmList<Color>,
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedText by remember { mutableStateOf(list) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(top = 20.dp)
    ) {
        ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
            expanded = expanded,
            onExpandedChange = {
                expanded = !expanded
            }
        ) {
            TextField(
                value = selectedText.toString(),
                onValueChange = {},
                readOnly = true,
                trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded).toString() },
                modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor()
            )

            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
            ) {
                list.forEach { item ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { list.toString() },
                        onClick = {
                            selectedText = list
                            expanded = false }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```